# React Native: RCTFatal + 668

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

[I've also posted the issue in the React Native github repo, hoping to get some insight into the error.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27387)

I've noticed that a not insignificant number of my iOS users experience the fatal error ( RCTFatal + 668 ) in production, resulting in the app crashing. The error occurs about 0.004 times per session, not terrible, but not great either.

There seems to be no correlation between the error and what iOS version the user is running, the number of crashes seems to be directly tied to the number of sessions for each iOS version. What iOS device the user has doesn't seem to correlate with the error either.

I'm unable to reproduce the error in local, staging, or production.

Has anyone else had this error, and what can i do to debug this issue further?

---

**react-native info**

```
System:
  OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
  CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7920HQ CPU @ 3.10GHz
  Memory: 189.93 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash

Binaries:
  Node: 12.8.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman

SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
  Android SDK:
    Android NDK: 20.0.5594570

IDEs:
  Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
  Xcode: 11.2.1/11B500 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild

npmPackages:
  react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
  react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2
```

---

**Screenshot from crashes tab in Xcode** (App name blurred for privacy)

[image]

---

***P.S** I'm aware that i'm not running the very latest version of RN. By the time i've upgraded RN, pushed to review, passed review, and got 2 weeks of crash reports there will always be a new version out. If this is known to be fixed in a later RN version, i will happily upgrade.*

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you try to "Open in Project"? Did that help at all?

Comment: I have. Unfortunately i can't seem to get any logs earlier than the invocation of the fatal error. I haven't been able to figure out the source/cause of the error.

Comment: There is probably no way to find what is wrong because it might either a bug in RN or something like with your code, since it is a generic error it might be anywhere.

Comment: Any solutions? What does 668 mean? I am now getting the same error.